# Vue - Running a function after another has completed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can't seem to figure out how to call a function after a function has run.

`Func1` is found in `componentA` `this.$refs.componentA.Func1()`

`Func2` is found in the local methods `this.Func2()`

How do I call a function after a function has completed.

I have tried variations of this code (promises), but it has an error :

```
this.$refs.componentA
            .Func1()
            .then(response => {
              this.Func2()
            });
```

Getting these errors:

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: If `Func1` isn't asynchronous, just call one after the other, ie `this.$refs.componentA.Func1(); this.Func2()`

Comment: Hey Phil - Func2() runs immediately after Func1 even though Func1 hasn't finished

Comment: So what's in `Func1`? Sounds like it's a poorly composed asynchronous function

Answer (score -2):

You can use callback function for Func1 or can use an alternative method to call function with Promise as :

```
Func1(Func2)
Or
Promise.resolve(Func1()).then(Func2)
```